# Include in Menu false but still subcategory is showing using Magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to hide some submenus from the Menu by using "Include in Menu = false" from the admin panel, but still, it's showing in Menu. please update if there is any solution to this.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes i have used command php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: also used php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Is there is any way to do this from the core file, if yes please assist me how could I do that?

Comment: Do you want to do it programmatically?If so are you using any csv to import the categories?

Comment: In Magento default or you are using some other third party megamenu module ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this script :

```
 <?php
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
        $categories = $categoryCollection->create();
        $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $categories->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq'=>2));
        $categories->load();
    ?>
      <?php
        foreach($categories as $category):
            $catId = $category->getId();
            $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
            $subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
            $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
            foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
                $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                $_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
                $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
                $sitebaseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
                $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();
                if (!$_category->getData('include_in_menu')) {

                    continue;

                }
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>" id="sub_<?php echo $subcat->getId();?>" class="<?php if($subcat->getChildrenCategories()->count()):?>child_sub<?php else:?> no-child<?php endif;?>">    
                <?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

How to create a hidden category?

```
You need to follow these steps.
1. Choose the Categories section into Product section on Admin sidebar to start configuration.
2. Select the category you want to hide in the category tree.
3. Then you must edit some field in General Information and Display Setting like this:
    General Information: Set Is Active and Include in Navigation Menu to No
    Display setting: Set Is Anchor to No

Just with these simple steps, you can hide a category. 
When you complete the configuration, tap Save Category.
```

Comment: What does this even mean? What "Categories section into Product section on Admin sidebar"?